# TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to display the output of each layer of the convolutions neural network.
The backend I'm using is TensorFlow.
Here is the code:

```
import ....
from keras import backend as K

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (1,28,28))) 
convout1 = Activation('relu')
model.add(convout1)

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist_dataset = mnist.load_data("mnist.pkl")
reshaped = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])


from random import randint
img_to_visualize = randint(0, len(X_train) - 1)


# Generate function to visualize first layer
# ERROR HERE
convout1_f = K.function([model.input(train=False)], convout1.get_output(train=False))   #ERROR HERE
convolutions = convout1_f(reshaped[img_to_visualize: img_to_visualize+1])
```

The full Error is:

> convout1_f = K.function([model.input(train=False)],
>   convout1.get_output(train=False)) TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not
>   callable

Any comment or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is my answer correct? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Both  `get_output` and `get_input` methods return either `Theano` or `TensorFlow` tensor. It's not callable because of the nature of this objects.

In order to compile a function you should provide only layer tensors and a special Keras tensor called  `learning_phase` which sets in which option your model should be called.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745821/keras-1-0-getting-intermediate-layer-output/36789699#36789699) your function should look like this:

```
convout1_f = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], convout1.get_output)
```

Remember that you need to pass either `True` or `False` when calling your function in order to make your model computations in either learning or training phase mode.