# ValueError: Unknown layer:name when loading a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I have trained a CNN and saved it accordingly:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
          epochs=epochs,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
model.save('full_model.h5')
```

I now try load  the model in another python script using the command:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('full_model.h5')
```

and receive the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/spt/Data/tensorflow_server/get_model.py", line 12, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('full_model.h5')
  File "/home/spt/.conda/envs/dev_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 229, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/spt/.conda/envs/dev_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 306, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/spt/.conda/envs/dev_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 64, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/spt/.conda/envs/dev_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 173, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/spt/.conda/envs/dev_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 286, in from_config
    layer = layer_module.deserialize(conf, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/spt/.conda/envs/dev_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 64, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/spt/.conda/envs/dev_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 193, in deserialize_keras_object
    function_name)
ValueError: Unknown layer:name
```

I came across more than one site describing the same/similar issue, e.g. [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180589/keras-valueerror-unknown-layername-when-trying-to-load-model-to-another-platf), [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11617). Typically the issue is an outdated version of Keras. But in my case, all Keras related packages are up to date (output of conda list for all keras related packages):

```
keras-applications        1.0.6                    py36_0
keras-base                2.2.4                    py36_0
keras-gpu                 2.2.4                         0
keras-preprocessing       1.0.5                    py36_0
```

Can anyone suggest how I can fix/troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Which versions of `tensorflow` and `tf.keras` do you use  (`tf.VERSION`,
`tf.keras.__version__`)? Is this model defined via `keras` or `tf.keras` and why do you use a `tf.keras` uploading a model, not a `keras`?

Comment: Try using `load_model` from `keras.models`

Comment: I am new to TF and Keras and was not aware that keras and tf.keras were different. After reading your comments I updated my TF and now it works. Thanks a lot! I am using tf.keras since I am trying to use TF Serving

Comment: For anyone still struggling with issues similar to this one, see @M. Viaz's answer (and my comment) to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183865/unknown-initializer-glorotuniform-when-loading-keras-model

Comment: I so wish someone would answer that

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a custom layer, you can load a keras model with such a layer as follows:

```
model = keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'MyCustomLayer': InstanceOfMyCustomLayer})
```

Comment: When I try the following, it does solve the error but it gives a different error as follows: `TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable`

Comment: Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911883/typeerror-tensor-object-is-not-callable) help?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, and It had been solved when I updated my Tensorflow and Keras version

Comment: Tensorflow 1.13.1 and keras 2.4

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while loading my custom trained EfficientNetB3 model using `tf.keras.models.load_model`. Importing the EfficientNetB3 model using `from efficientnet.tfkeras import EfficientNetB3` solved the issue.